# Serialization for similar objects both list and string

Tags: java

I am trying to serialize my payload so I have "value" object in 2 different type list and string. I tried serializedName, however, its not working..Do you have any other suggestions?

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Setter
@Getter
public class AttributesPIM {

  private String name = null;
  @SerializedName("value")
      private List<List<Value>> values = null;
      private Object value = null;
}
```

Comment: Without implementing the `Serializable` interface?

Comment: yes@Aristotelis